# Finding $Aeven(x)$ and $Aodd(x)$ for a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) problem?

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

In this [article](https://medium.com/@aiswaryamathur/understanding-fast-fourier-transform-from-scratch-to-solve-polynomial-multiplication-8018d511162f) about FFT the author used FFT on this polynomial.

$A(x) = 3+2x+3x^2+4x^3$

Using $ A(x)= Aeven(x^2) + xAodd(x^2)$ the author determined the following for $Aeven(x)$ and $Aodd(x)$

$ Aeven(x) = 3+3x$

$ Aodd(x) = 2+4x $

How were $Aeven(x)$ and $Aodd(x)$ determined? Shouldn't $Aeven(x) = 3+3x^2$ and $Aodd(x) = 2x+4x^3$ ?

Answer (score 2):

You have $Aeven(x^2) = 3 + 3x^2$, so that means that $Aeven(x) = 3 + 3x$.

For $Aodd$, you have $xAodd(x^2) = 2x + 4x^3$, so $Aodd(x^2) = 2 + 4x^2$, hence $Aodd(x) = 2 + 4x$.

Comment: So for $Aodd(x)$ did you simply replace $x^2$ with $x$  instead of doing a $\sqrt{}$ of $Aodd(x)$ ?

Comment: Why would I calculate the square root of $Aodd(x)$?? The equation is $Aodd(x^2) = 2 + 4x^2$, not $Aodd(x)^2 = 2 + 4x^2$. Just suppose $X=x^2$ and replace each $x^2$ by $X$.

Comment: Sorry. I meant $ Aodd(x^2) $. But if we are merely replacing $X^2$ with $X$, then if $Aodd(x^2) = 2x$ , what would $Aodd(x)$ be? @Nathaniel

Comment: I sincerely (without trying to offend you) suggest that you try to review basic math and function manipulation before trying to understand FFT which is quite complicated.

Comment: If $Aodd(x^2) = 2x$ then  $Aodd(x) = 2 $. That is the answer . See reference at https://youtu.be/bR1PD-Hn6t8?t=600